# How to deserealize multiple nested elements in Jackson?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jackson, pojo

I need to build a parser to parse an `XML` file to a `Java` object.
I use `Jackson` to do this and followed the steps provided in [THIS](https://stackabuse.com/serialize-and-deserialize-xml-in-java-with-jackson/) tutorial.

In the tutorial is a section '*Manipulating Nested Elements and Lists in XML*'. I followed it, but unfortunately I can't get the desired output of all my required elements - I want to output first and last of all my authors. And I only get it for my last author in the `XML`-file like this:

```
[{nameList={person={first=Karl, last=S}}}]
```

My `XML` file looks like this.

```
<sources>
<Doi>123456789</Doi>
<Title>Title</Title>
<author>
    <editor>
        <nameList>
            <person>
                <first>Peter</first>
                <last>Parker</last>
            </person>
        </nameList>
    </editor>
</author>
<Source>
    <SourceType>Book</SourceType>
    <ShortTitle>Book Title</ShortTitle>
    <Author>
        <Editor>
            <NameList />
        </Editor>
    </Author>
</Source>
<author>
    <bookAuthor>
        <nameList>
            <person>
                <first>Karl</first>
                <last>S</last>
            </person>
        </nameList>
    </bookAuthor>
</author>
<Source>
    <SourceType>Journal</SourceType>
    <ShortTitle>ABC Journal</ShortTitle>
</Source>
</sources>
```

How can I deserealize the entire XML file?

My code looks like this:
MyClass.java

```
private static void jacksonXmlFileToObject() throws IOException {

    System.out.println("jacksonXmlFileToObject");

    InputStream xmlFile = Publication.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.xml");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();

    // Configure
    mapper
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    try {

        Sources deserializedData = mapper.readValue(xmlFile, Sources.class);

        System.out.println(deserializedData);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sources.java

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "sources") public class Sources {
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "author")
@Getter
@Setter
private Object[] author;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return Arrays.toString(author);
}

public Sources() {
}
}
```

I would be very happy about some help.

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you have `<author>` and `<Source>` mixed nodes.  If you need authors it means, you need to skip all `<Source>` nodes, am I right?. And why your output does not contain `Peter Parker`?

Comment: @MichałZiober Thank you for your reply. Yes, I have mixed nodes, but I only want to have the authors, respectively `first` and `last`. And I am not sure why my output does not contain `Peter Parker`?

Answer (score 2):

**Use the `JsonMerge` annotation.**

I had a similar problem myself recently, and found out that the annotation `@JsonMerge` solves the problem.

I have simplified the XML a little:

```xml
<sources>
    <author>
        <name>Jack</name>
    </author>
    <source>
        <type>Book</type>
    </source>
    <author>
        <name>Jill</name>
    </author>
    <source>
        <type>Journal</type>
    </source>
</sources>
```

With the classes `Author` and `Source`

```java
class Author {
    String name;
}
class Source {
    String type;
}
```

The `Sources` class looks as follows:

```java
class Sources {

    // We prevent each <author> tag to be wrapped in an <authors> container tag
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)

    // Each element is <author> and not <authors> (and we named our field 'authors')
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "author")

    // This is the property which solves your problem. It causes non-subsequent elements with the
    // same name to be merged into the existing list
    @JsonMerge
    private List<Author> authors;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "source")
    @JsonMerge
    private List<Source> sources;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `JacksonXmlElementWrapper` does not work when the same elements are not following each other. Regular `XML` should contain the same nodes listed one after another. When other node starts it's mean previous node section is finished. To handle your case we need to write custom deserialiser: manually read all authors and skip the rest of nodes. Example code could look like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonPointer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class XmlMapperApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File xmlFile = new File("./resource/test.xml").getAbsoluteFile();

        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();

        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(xmlFile, Sources.class));
    }
}

class SourcesJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Sources> {

    private final JsonPointer EDITOR = JsonPointer.compile("/editor/nameList/person");
    private final JsonPointer BOOK_AUTHOR = JsonPointer.compile("/bookAuthor/nameList/person");

    @Override
    public Sources deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        List<JsonNode> authors = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonToken token;
        while ((token = p.currentToken()) != null) {
            if (token == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                if ("author".equals(p.getText())) {
                    authors.add(getPersonObject(p));
                }
            }
            p.nextToken();
        }

        Sources sources = new Sources();
        sources.setAuthors(authors);

        return sources;
    }

    private JsonNode getPersonObject(JsonParser p) throws IOException {
        // read start object
        p.nextToken();

        // read the whole object as node
        ObjectNode author = p.readValueAsTree();

        // try to evaluate /editor/* path
        JsonNode pair = author.at(EDITOR);
        if (pair.isMissingNode()) {
            // must be bookAuthor
            pair = author.at(BOOK_AUTHOR);
        }

        return pair;
    }
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = SourcesJsonDeserializer.class)
class Sources {

    private List<JsonNode> authors;

    public List<JsonNode> getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }

    public void setAuthors(List<JsonNode> authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return authors + "";
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
[{"first":"Peter","last":"Parker"}, {"first":"Karl","last":"S"}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your example.
How can you make sure that you can deserealize multiple tags in a tag?

I tried a different approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57297149/how-to-parse-xml-file-containing-multiple-tags-using-linkedhashmap), but got stuck on the same challenge here as well.